Math mode: bold with hat
In the past, I remember in math mode I used to write, say, \bm{\hat{n}} and it would work. Working in lualatex I had the error Missing number, treated as zero. and the output below. But \hat{\bm{n}} works. Is that how it should have been anyway, or am I doing something wrong?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2]
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
    n,\hat{n},\bm{n},\bm{\hat{n}},\hat{\bm{n}}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}



Off-topic: Since you employ Libertinus Serif as the document's text font, you may want to employ a somewhat more compatible math font, by executing \setmathfont{Libertinus Math} instead of \setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2].

@Mico Thanks! The truth is I am still confused about that topic. Is there such a list or topic as to what good-looking-math-fonts are aesthetically compatible with what good looking text font, or vice verse?

The topic of which fonts mesh well and which ones do not is unavoidably subjective, I'm afraid. That said, chances that Libertinus Serif and Libertinus Math will mesh well must certainly be a lot better than those of Libertinus Serif (text) and Times Roman (math) meshing well.

@Mico In this site I remember reading to stay away from Libertinus Math if using lualatex. In either case, if you think you can share your own opinion for combos, I am all ears.

Sorry, but that's a very broad statement; in particular, the supposed inferiority of Libertinus Math under LuaLaTeX seems hoaky. How long ago do you think you came across that claim? These days, OpenType math fonts are constantly being updated and improved. What may have been true 6 or even 3 months ago may thus no longer apply. For sure, if I take the code in David Carlisle's answer and merely replace \setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2] with \setmathfont{Libertinus Math}, I experience no issues whatsoever.

\bm{\hat{n}} and \hat{\bm{n}} are both valid bm syntax but different: the first is a bold hat on a bold n, the second is a normal weight hat on a bold n.
But you have implicitly loaded unicode-math as evidenced by the use of \setmathfont  and the bm package is mostly incompatible with unicode-math.
With unicode-math you can use \hat{\symbfit{n}}, no other package is needed.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[version=Stix2]
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
    n,\hat{n},\symbfit{n},\hat{\symbfit{n}}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}


+1. :-) Is there a need for the amsfonts package, given that unicode-math supplies its own list of macros?

@Mico ooh good call it shouldn't be there, amsmath is also not needed as unicode-math loads that as well, but amsfonts just doesn't work with unicode it's relying on unicode-math to undo it
